# How to use side-by-side boxplots to assess assumptions of a 2 sample test?

Tags: normality-assumption, assumptions, boxplot

Here is the context:

[image]

So we can analyse this using a 2 sample t tests. The assumptions of t-test comparing the means of two independent samples are populations being compared should follow normal distribution and independent samples.

I have two diagnostic plots essentially to test the assumptions. How do you test independence ness from these plots?
Here is my attempt to check normality:
For catalyst 1, it seems to be normally distributed from the normal probability plots and from the boxplot (by comparing the spread of the box). Catalyst 2, seems to be right skewed I think from the box plot. Are there any way to check for independence from the plots?

[image]

Comment: What is the "percentage" on the $y$-axis of your left plot?